# 404 or 500 errors when attempting to access Laravel routes

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess

I’m having some issues getting my Laravel project up and running on a shared hosting account. Of course, this works fine locally and it was working fine on the hosting account a couple days ago; I'm not sure what I could have changed to make it stop working.

Being that it’s a shared host, I don’t think I have the ability to change `httpd.conf`, but I can of course modify `.htaccess`.

I wanted a place to store multilple apps, so my plan was to create a new folder in my web root for each Laravel project.  This is how I currently have it set up (not sure if this is a good way to do it or not):

- http://example.com/App1
- http://example.com/App2

Then map the public folder of each of these folders to a subdomain:

- http://app1.domain.com  => pointing to App1/public
- http://app2.domain.com => pointing to App2/public

Here’s the problem: when I try to hit any route besides the root page `'/'`, I get a `404` error.  This is the generic 404 from the host, not from Laravel.  When I try to access via the subdomain, I get a `500` error.

If I visit:

- http://example.com/App1/public => **works!**
- http://example.com/App1/public/route2 => **`404 error`**
- http://example.com/App1/public/index.php/route2 => **works!**
- http://app1.example.com => **works!**
- http://app1.example.com/route2 => **`500 error`** (*error happens immediately*)

I’ve seen other questions that mention changing settings in `httpd.conf`, but I don’t believe I have access to do that. Given that this was previously working for me, I think there is a solution outside of that.

**What can I do to prevent these errors?**

Also, why would I get different errors when hitting the page from http://example.com/App1/public vs http://app1.example.com ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated..!

Not sure if this will help, but here’s my .htaccess code (Laravel 5.4.21 default):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What kind of 500 error do you get? From host or from application? 500 from application will leave a log in `laravel.log` if you set `APP_DEBUG` to `true`

Comment: Thanks @MarcoAurélioDeleu, unfortunately this is just the generic `500 Internal Server Error`, not from Laravel

Comment: https://snag.gy/QbatNW.jpg

Comment: Sounds like your `.htaccess` is not being processed. Might be file permission or the server blocking it.

Comment: Thanks again. I verified that .htaccess is getting processed.  (I added a bunch of invalid text an saved it; after got 500 error; after changing it back, page loaded normally).  Issue still persists with other routes though

Comment: looks like adding `RewriteBase /` did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was resolved by modifying the Laravel default `.htaccess` file by adding the line:

```
RewriteBase /
```

This fixed both the `404` and `500` errors.

So altogether:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```